# particles facing to camera and random rotation

Tags: particles

Basically i wanna make a "cheap" smoke simulation with just one smoke image.

So the vehicle drives, a moving emitter is on the wheel.

The emitter emits these smoke png, which i know how to face them to the cam.

i do that by running a script and updating:

```
def update_track_constr(scene):
    
    object.constraints["Damped Track"].target = bpy.context.scene.camera
```

Object in that case is the smoke image, which is also the rendered object of the particle system.

Now i want to rotate each particle randomly on the axis (particle to camera) so that the images are still facing the camera, but each in another angle (the angle can be constant over the lifetime of the particle simulation, but it should be different per particle).

How can i achieve that?

i tried with checking rotation and trying out all axis - didn't work.

[image]

the selected planes are my particles, the annotation arrow hopefully makes it clear, how they should rotate. You can easily see, that they are all rotated at the same angle.